Non-repeating of sine function with irrational coefficient
The problem arose in the PDE lecture, consider the function
$$ v(t) = \frac{ w \sin(t) - \sin(wt) }{w^2-1}.$$
It is said that the function $v(t)$ is periodic when $w$ is a rational number; while $v(t)$ is not periodic when $w$ is an irrational number. However, I don't quite understand the reason.

Hint:  the two functions, $\sin(t)$ and $\sin (\omega t)$ are both periodic, but you need them to have a common period.

If $w=p/q$ for some integers $p$ and $q>0$, then a possible period is $2\pi q$, since it's a period for both $\sin(t)$ and $\sin(wt)$.
If $w$ is irrational and there's a period $T$ by contradiction, $T$ is a period for the derivatives of $v$ too. In particular, $v^{(4n)}(t)=w\sin(t)-w^{4n}\sin(wt)$ (constant apart). Therefore for a fixed $t$, we have
$$\sin(t)-\sin(t+T)=w^{4n-1}(\sin(wt)-\sin(w(t+T)))$$
for all integers $n$, which implies that $\sin(t)=\sin(t+T)$ and $\sin(wt)=\sin(w(t+T))$ (note that $w\neq 0,-1,1$), so $T$ is a period for both $\sin(t)$ and $\sin(wt)$. But this is impossible since $w$ is irrational.
I came up with this proof after realizing that more direct computations are a bit ugly. At that point I thought about comparing the analytic expressions, for a more global approach, which made me think that looking at derivatives could be enough.
The general intuition with this kind of problem is always the same, and it's almost always right: if the periods aren't compatible, you won't find a period of any kind for any combination of these functions.
